# How can you mirror the stdout of one terminal to another one?

Tags: terminal, mirror

I'm not sure if I'm phrasing the question correctly, but let's say that I have two virtual terminals open, and if I typed `ls` in one of them, I'd get the contents of the directory in **both** of them (the second one doesn't have to be writable, it only needs to display the stdout of the first one).  How would I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As geekosaur mentioned `screen` will do what you need (and much much much more).

First, create a named screen session for convenience in your first terminal:

```
$ screen -S foo
```

Second, attach to the screen session in your second terminal:

```
$ screen -x foo
```

Comment: Thanks.  This expands on geekosaur's answer, and explains what I need to do, but all of them were helpful, so I thumbs up'd the rest.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `script` to do this.

For example, if you want to copy all your output to `/dev/tty1` you would run

```
script -f /dev/tty1
```

From then on anything you type, and all command output will be duplicated on `/dev/tty1`.
`script` launches another shell, so when youre done, you can just type `exit` to end `script`.

The `-f` is to make it real-time. Othewise `/dev/tty1` will only see the output when a complete line is displayed (when a newline char is written to the tty).

Answer (score 2):

Depends on exactly what you're looking for.  An easy solution is `script(1)`; GNU `screen` in multiattach mode is a fancier solution.

Comment: `script(1)` isn't exactly what I'm looking for; I'm looking for something in real-time.  How do I use `screen` in multi-attach mode?

Comment: `script` will buffer output; depending on the implementation you can suppress this (on FreeBSD and Mac OS X, `script -t 0`), then `tail -f typescript` in the other window). With `screen` you want something like `screen -S mysession` in the first terminal and `screen -x -r mysession` in the second.